# Why am I unable to run a program on the Anaconda Prompt?

Tags: python, command-prompt

I have a Python file called log_reg that I'm just trying to run in the anaconda prompt. I use the following commands:

```
cd Desktop
cd ML_models
python log_reg.py
```

I hit enter, and I don't get and error, but I also don't get any result or the file I'm trying to run. What should I do?

Comment: Please show us the code in `log_reg.py`, and logs after hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

You should try running your code from the command line and see if it works. Go to the command line and type python log_reg.py and see if it runs. If so you'll know your code is correct. Then you can try running it at the Anaconda prompt.